# How do stock markets react to economic data like consumer price index, home sales, and job data?

Tags: stocks, trading, bonds, stock-analysis, international-finance

Where can I learn about how the stock market reacts with the consumer price index, home market market numbers, bond interest rates, fed interest rates , GDP change, how the euro bond market affects the United States market.  Economic data reaction to market. Any books or course?

Answer (score 2):

In the 90s there was a toy called the bumble ball.  The bumble ball was a ball with a gyroscope in the center and bumpstops attached to the circumference.  The gyroscope would spin in the middle causing the ball to change direction whenever it bumped in to something making its movements very unpredictable.

The stock market is the ball and the all the data you mention is the gyroscope in the center.

Answer (score 0):

There are dozens of books on macro investing.

Another way of learning macro investing is to get involved as a currency trader. The supplemental currency-trading websites have economic-report calendars and real-time reporting of economic-report releases.

Comment: I like the question because it is not a "joe genre". A joe-genre would say "Why invest in the stock market if it is going to drastically react to every little economic report?". In other words a joe-genre finds drastic problems with widely popular financial situations. But I don't advocate censoring joe-genres, I just note them. "Joe" comes from the movie "The Russia House" as my-joe-has-gone-over-to-the-other-side.